# What are actually Spatiotemporal patterns?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory, nonlinear-dynamics

What actually we do mean by spatiotemporal patterns?.For example Chimera states?.If simply in a network of coupled oscillators there re a set of synchronized and desynchronized nodes then will it be a chimera state or does it have to satisfy some additional conditions?.

Seeing [Chimera states as an example of Spatiotemporal patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatiotemporal_pattern) it mentions that it has to satisfy some pattern formation rules?.

Any good reference/video where it explains what additional requirement is there in order for classifying a state to be a chimera state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spatial patterns means the distribution varies in space and temporal means the distribution varies in time.

So Spatiotemporal pattern means the distribution of the pattern is a variable of both space and time.